# How to remove empty line after for loop?

Tags: spacing, align, loops, line

[image]

Please go through code

```
\begin{align*}
 For(j=0;j\leq n-1;j++)   
 \end{align*}
 \vspace*{0.01cm}
  \\*\hspace*{2.4cm}\{ 
   \begin{align*}
  \hspace*{1.5cm}For(i=0,i\leq n-1;i++)  
  \end{align*}              
  \\*\hspace*{3.2cm}\{ 
 \\*\hspace*{4cm}$b_{j} . a_{i} = A_{j}[i]$;   
  \\*\hspace*{3.1cm} \} 
 \\*\hspace*{2.4cm} \}
```

After first for loop one empty line is created and for second for loop also.Is there any way to remove those empty lines. And if there is any other code format, i need structure of for loop as shown in figure. please help me in this removing empty line.

Comment: Remove `\vspace*{0.01cm}
  \\*`, however, from your image can be concluded that you actually write psevdocode. For this is intended package `listings` (see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf)  Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: I have removed \vspace{0.01cm}   but still i am getting empty line. can you please post the code where empty line is not created.

Comment: You need also to remove `\\*` in the next line ...

Comment: @JaswanthVuggirala, although I strongly recommend that you follow Zarko's suggestions and take a look at [`listings`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) or [`minted`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) pacakages. They are meant for this Kind of writing (code writing). `minted` can even process the sub and superscripts from math (maybe `listings` can too but I do not know) and they allow line breaks as well.

Comment: @Zarko, Thank you so much. listings did worked for me.